# How to create a folder in the same directory as the web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, tomcat, path

Let's say my web application's on development stage in Eclipse, at path `C:\eclipse\workspace\myapp` (Windows).

I intend to make it generate a folder at the same directory level (`C:\eclipse\workspace\myappfiles`) to store uploaded files (via `new File()`) in it.

However, at production stage, my web application will be at path `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/myapp` (Linux). It should then store files in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/myappfiles`.

**How can I detect those paths to write the folder and files?**

I experimented with some `java.io.File` methods, but it seemed to not have a default method that suits me for the task.

**EDIT :**

I need the path like that so I could map the path for direct file access via URL.

Comment: Just a comment, this is a pretty bad idea in practice, you'd expect to store the files in some sort of file system like say like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As david99world says in his comment: This is a **really bad idea**. Plus, it might not even work on future versions of tomcat or on different configurations: Tomcat can be set up not to have "exploded" webapplications at all - e.g. run from zipped `*.war` files. Also, tomcat might not have write permissions  to its own webapps directory (a basic precaution done to harden the system).

Imagine someone is uploading a file named "explorer.jsp" with a basic file explorer implemented in a jsp: Without taking care of it, tomcat will happily interpret this as code that needs to be executed server-side.

What you want to do is:

- Find a upload directory, somewhere, and store your files there.
- Write a download servlet that serves the files from that location.

You'll need a *little* bit more work this way, but the resulting installation is so much more secure out-of-the-box.

Comment: That's @david99world's comment.

Answer (score 1):

There are no standard ways to get the Tomcat path from Tomcat itself.   You can try to find the working directory of the Tomcat user, but this may change based on where you start the server from.  The safest way to do this is add the location of any files your application creates to your configuration, and then have your webapp check the config for this location.

One simple way and portable way to do this is to place the location of `myappfiles` in your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.example.mycompany.MyServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>appfilesdir</param-name>
    <param-value>/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/myappfiles</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Then use GenericServlet.getInitParameter from within your servlet to read it and use it:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private String myAppFilesDir;

    public void init(ServletConfig config)
      throws ServletException
    {
       myAppFilesDir = getInitParameter("appfilesdir");
    }

}
```

Comment: Understood, and a good practice.  In this case you are not really hardcoding where your app is, but where your apps working files are.  As indicated in the comments, it's a good approach to separate those two as this allows you to upgrade the servlet container without affecting files that your app requires.   However, if you want to consistently define where your app is, you should use @KayKay's solution, making sure to always define CATALINA_HOME, or use your own environmental variable to avoid problems in cases where multiple tomcats are deployed on the same machine.

Answer (score -1):

It should get the job done :

```
File currentDirectory = new File("");
String commonPath = currentDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
commonPath = commonPath.substring(path.lastIndexOf(File.separator) + 1);
File myFilesDir = new File(commonPath + "myappfiles");
myFilesDir.mkdirs();
```